# how do I execute Verilog in order when writing testBench?

Tags: verilog

below is my Verilog code

```
//code 1
integer i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)
begin
    a = %random(seed1);
    b = %random(seed2);
    #10 result = a + b; 
    if(sum !== result)
        err = err + 1;
end
```

but I have to wait for 1100 ns to check the value of err

```
//code 2
initial
begin
    #1100 
    if(err !== 0)
    .....
end
```

how I want Verilog execute code 2 after code 1,

but I don't want to tell code it should be 1100ns,

how could I edit my code?

I want to know how could I edit code 2

Answer (score 0):

You may add a flag to represent the end of code 1 execution. In code 1, set the flag when all things are done. In code 2, wait for the flag is set then start execution. For example,

```
reg code1_done;
// code 1
initial
begin
  ...
  code1_done = 1;
end

// code 2
initial
begin
  wait ( code1_done === 1 );
  ...
end
```

Comment: likealways@(code1_done==1)?

Comment: If code 2 will be executed only once, no need to use an always block.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that code 1 is within an initial block, any code that is written below code 1 in the same initial block will be executed sequentially. So instead of a separate initial block for code 2, you may place code 2 content after code 1 as shown below and it should execute sequentially

```
initial begin
    ...

    //code 1
    integer i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)
    begin
        a = %random(seed1);
        b = %random(seed2);
        #10 result = a + b; 
        if(sum !== result)
            err = err + 1;
    end

    // code 2
    if(err !== 0)
    .....

end
```